# Understanding a quotient of a polynomial algebra

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, and consider the quotient of the polynomial algebra $k[x,y]$ by the ideal generated by the polynomials $x(x-1), y(y-1),$ and $(x-1)(y-1)$. I understand that in this quotient, we have $$x(x-1)=y(y-1)=(x-1)(y-1)=0.$$ Is there a way to simplify the quotient in question using the Chinese remainder theorem, in the same way one might write the quotient of $k[z]$ by $z(z-1)$ as a product of two copies of $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an isomorphism
$$\begin{align*}k[x,y]/(x(x-1),y(y-1),(x-1)(y-1))&\to k^3\\f(x,y)&\mapsto (f(0,1),f(1,0),f(1,1)).\end{align*}$$
Indeed, both spaces have dimension $3$ (the first space has basis $\{1,x,y\}$), and it is surjective: $$1-x\mapsto(1,0,0),1-y\mapsto (0,1,0),x+y-1\mapsto(0,0,1).$$

Comment: So if I understood correctly, the Chinese remainder theorem need not be invoked?

Comment: It also follows from CRT by observing $(x(x-1),y(y-1),(x-1)(y-1))=(x,y-1)(x-1,y)(x-1,y-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The three relations may also be written
$$x^2=x,\quad y^2=y,\quad xy=x+y-1$$
hence the quotient is simply $k\oplus kx\oplus ky$ with the multiplication defined by
$$(a+bx+cy)(a'+b'x+c'y)=$$$$aa'+(ab'+ba'+bb')x+(ac'+ca'+cc')y+(bc'+cb')(x+y+1).$$

Comment: This is understandable from Kenta S's answer, which is much better than mine (though both are correct).